# Can we define component of a matrix which is orthogonal to another matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, definition

Given two vectors $A$ and $B$ one can easily find component of $A$ along $B$ and component of $A$ perpendicular/orthogonal to $B$ and vice versa. This is possible as we can define dot product of two vectors. As I understand if $A$ and $B$ are matrix then our dot product does not make sense, does it? If not is there a way to define component and orthogonal component of a matrix with respect to the other? Or there is no such concepts for matrices?

Comment: The function $\;\langle A,B\rangle:= Tr. (B^tA)\;$ is a dot product in the linear space of square (real) matrices $\;n\times n\;$

Comment: Since matrices are vectors, we can do anything with a matrix as we do with a vector.  But what does it mean for two matrices to be orthogonal to one another?

Comment: @DougM Exactly the same as with vectors: that their dot product is zero.

Comment: @DougM exactly, that is my question. As I understand there is no such thing which is defined so far, is not it? We can do any operation treating the matrix as a collection of vectors but does it all makes sense in some practical context?

Comment: Keep in mind that *every* scalar product defines a notion of orthogonality and that there are many such scalar products besides the familiar dot product.

Answer (score 3):

The **Frobenius inner product** of matrices $A, B \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ is defined by

$$\langle A, B\rangle := \mbox{tr} (A^T B) = \mbox{tr} (B A^T) = \mbox{tr} (A B^T) = \mbox{tr} (B^T A)$$

For example, the standard basis "vectors" for $\mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ are

$$M_{11} := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad \quad M_{12} := \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad \quad M_{21} := \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \qquad \quad M_{22} := \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that

$$\langle M_{11}, M_{11}\rangle = 1 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{11}, M_{12}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{11}, M_{21}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{11}, M_{22}\rangle = 0$$

$$\langle M_{12}, M_{11}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{12}, M_{12}\rangle = 1 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{12}, M_{21}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{12}, M_{22}\rangle = 0$$

$$\langle M_{21}, M_{11}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{21}, M_{12}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{21}, M_{21}\rangle = 1 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{21}, M_{22}\rangle = 0$$

$$\langle M_{22}, M_{11}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{22}, M_{12}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{22}, M_{21}\rangle = 0 \qquad \qquad \langle M_{22}, M_{22}\rangle = 1$$

Comment: It is also known as the [Hilbert-Schmidt inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator).  It is notable that it coincides with the usual notion of the dot-product, which is to say that
$$
\langle A,B \rangle = \sum_{i}\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij}
$$

Comment: Also, this is not explicitly stated in the answer, but since we have an inner product, we can indeed define the component of $A$ which is orthogonal/parallel to $B$ just as one would define it using the dot-product.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you, i was about to ask, if such orthogonal matrices can be defined if so does it have any significance?

Comment: I would say that while we do have all the usual structure of a vector space, the notion of an orthogonal projection does gain much *additional* significance when applied to matrices.  That being said, there is an interesting bit about two *projection* matrices being orthogonal to each other, and it is notable that the symmetric matrices and skew-symmetric matrices are orthogonal complements to each other.  This inner product is particularly important in the study of positive definite matrices, especially in the context of quantum information theory.

Answer (score 3):

There is such a thing called orthogonal matrix in linear algebra. An orthogonal matrix is a square matrix with real entries whose columns and rows are orthogonal unit vectors: $$AA^T=I$$ Each entry is a dot product of a column of $A$ with an other column of $A$.
Orthogonal matrices preserve dot products, the length of vectors as well
as the angles between them: $Ax\cdot Ay=x\cdot y$

Comment: Seemingly, the only connection between this answer and the question given is that it involves the word "orthogonal" in some capacity